# make viewWillDisapear wait for animation to finish

Tags: ios6, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uianimation

So my issue is that in my viewWillDisapear I call a method that runs a animation (a bounce on the main view) but it doesn't wait for the animation to finish (since this runs in it's own thread). I need a way to make the execution stop till the uiAnimation is finished. i tried sleep() but for some reason this also pauses the actual animation.
What I realy need to happen is for the view to have a small bounce before it is slid of the screen. I am also open to any sugestions on how i can achieve this differently.

Comment: What's the trigger for your view disappearing?

Comment: I'm using [navigationController popViewController]

Comment: Are you open to critiques of your app design, or are you set on making this animation finish?

Comment: I just need a way to make the view bonce before it slides of the screen (since im poping th controller with animation set to YES)